# ISNULL function combined with TOP 1 command

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

I'm currently creating an statistic report using jaspersoft iReport 5.6.0 and MSSQL Server v17 in order to check on the malfunctioning sql.

In that report some statements (like "ALBRabatt") are part of calculations so they are multiplied, divided and so on.

So the result of this statement cannot be "NULL", hence I'm trying to solve this using ISNULL.

But i have trouble with following statement:

```
ISNULL  
(  
      (  
        select top 1 rabatt  
        from artikellieferant  
        left join artikel on artikel.artikel=artikellieferant.artikel  
        where artikel.artikel=artikellieferant.artikel   
        order by artikellieferant.gueltigvon asc  
    ),  
    0  
    ) AS ALBRabatt
```

Error Message:

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>       Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.*

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Try `SELECT ISNULL` instead of `ISNULL`.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the critical issue is missing the SELECT keyword.
A minor issue is the WHERE clause here just repeats what the join condition do, plus requiring a match is really found, so after turning your join from LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN, it can be removed without changing the query logic.

```sql
select 
  ISNULL  
  (  
    (  
      select top 1 rabatt  
      from artikellieferant  
      inner join artikel on artikel.artikel=artikellieferant.artikel  
      order by artikellieferant.gueltigvon asc  
    ),  
    0  
  ) AS ALBRabatt
```

Comment: I agree. Thanks for pointing this out. Modified in my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ISNULL()` inside query :

```
select top 1 ISNULL(rabatt, 0)
from artikellieferant left join 
     artikel 
     on artikel.artikel=artikellieferant.artikel
where artikel.artikel = artikellieferant.artikel -- redundant where clause
order by artikellieferant.gueltigvon asc
```

However, your query syntax looks correct for me.

Assuming table `artikel` coming from outer query if so, just do *correlation* :

```
( SELECT TOP (1) ISNULL(art.rabatt, 0)
  FROM artikellieferant art
  WHERE art.artikel = artikel.artikel
) AS AS ALBRabatt
```

If table position is wrong, then just swap the table & adjust the column accordingly.

Comment: There is a difference. OP's approach covers the possibility that the query returns zero rows; yours does not. One may argue that that is an unlikely scenario since the query has hardly any `WHERE` conditions (the tables would have to be empty), but in my experience those conditions will soon change as the product matures.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL  
(  
      (  
        select top 1 rabatt  
        from artikellieferant  
        left join artikel on artikel.artikel=artikellieferant.artikel  
        where artikel.artikel=artikellieferant.artikel   
        order by artikellieferant.gueltigvon asc  
    ),  
    0  
    ) AS ALBRabatt
```